# Do Barbarians not count as a Civilization for theming bonuses?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I have the Uffizi which has a theming bonus of all Art from the same Era and Civilization.

As seen below I have three from the Barbarians all from the Ancient Era and I am not getting the theming bonus.

So

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Are Barbarians not a Civilization?  If not what would be the point of getting Barbarian artifacts over random civilization artifacts?
3. Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is not that barbarians aren't a civilization, but that you're not displaying *art*.

Art specifically refers to the paintings produced by a Great Artist, and *not* the Artifacts recovered by your archaeologists.

Comment: Doh, you're right.